# How to fix not found error with heroku deployment / no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

First, sorry for my poor English.

The problem is this.

---

Whenever I try to open heroku I get this screen:

Not Found

---

Whenever I try to heroku logs I get this screen:

2022-05-20T09:26:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
...

2022-05-20T09:26:08.430002+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoDB database connection established successfully
...

2022-05-20T09:32:21.525922+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=protected-wildwood-11173.herokuapp.com request_id=f33e9e00-7573-4fa5-9ebf-7e9c54d04532 fwd="121.134.103.64" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=412 protocol=https

**2022-05-20T09:32:21.526199+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'**

---

And this is my codes

1. [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTcPL.png)
2. [folder path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s8ib.png)
3. [server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twkvV.png)

---

- In my expectation

1. Heroku cannot cognize 'build'
2. wrong path ( server.js - deployment )

---

I haven't been able to do it for 7 days.

Please help me
crycrycry...

Comment: Are you trying to deploy react app using express server or there is more usecase of express server like api calls to do crud oparaions ?

Comment: I re-uploaded the picture. ( server.js )

Comment: I changed the deployment. and it works

Comment: // Server static assets if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
  
    app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}